# How to delete all QGraphicsItem from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, incomplete-type

I've written a derived class from `QGraphicsScene`. At a point I need to remove all items from the scene and I want the items to be physically destroyed (destructor called). I tried the following:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> all = items();
for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
{
    QGraphicsItem *gi = all[i];
    removeItem(gi);
    delete gi; // warning at this line
}
```

Qt Creator emits a warning: warning: C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'QGraphicsItem'; no destructor called

I'm not sure why is that. `QGraphicsItem` has virtual destructor so the items should be deleted from memory.

If this is not the right way, how can I delete all `QGraphicsItem`s from `QGraphicsScene`? Note that I know when the scene is deleted, all items will also be deleted. But i want to remove items from scene and draw other items. I want the removed items to be deleted from memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can remove and delete all items with [QGraphicsScene::clear()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#clear).

Comment: Note `clear` doesn't seem to call `removeItem` or trigger `itemChange` events (`ItemSceneChange`). Looking at the source code, if you have code that relies on removal events to centralize some cleanup code, etc,  it may be better to subclass and use `removeItem` for each top level item, for max reuse. Might be heavier but seems reasonable at a glance. Please comment if this is a bad idea.

Comment: Note that `QGraphicsScene::clear()` will call `delete` to all `QGraphicsItem`s, even if they are class members! Obviously, if those are not pointers, this will cause an exception.

Answer (score 12):

Like **jpalecek** pointed out, you are missing the header file. You should accept his answer. I am just going to point out two potential issues:

First of all, you don't need to call `QGraphicsScene::removeItem()`. `QGraphicsItem::~QGraphicsItem()` does that for you.

Secondly. Be careful if you put any `QGraphicsItem` inside of others. That is, you have items that are children of other items. The destructor of `QGraphicsItem` automatically delete all its children. So when you loop through the items returned from `QGraphicsScene`, you may end up deleting a child item that has already been deleted by its parent. For example, say you have 2 items, A and B, and B is a child of A. When you delete A, B is deleted automatically. And then you get to B and try to delete it. BOOM!

A safer way to do this is to test if the item is the top level one, i.e. it has no parent:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> all = items();
for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
{
    QGraphicsItem *gi = all[i];
    if(gi->parentItem()==NULL) {
        delete gi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>
```

in that file. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know what `QGraphicsItem` is, that it has a virtual destructor, etc.